# How to avoid JSON text sent in multi-part form-data of postman from getting attached to email

Tags: json, postman, mulesoft

I am trying to write an email service in `Mule 3.8`. I am using postman form-data to send attachments(files) along with the text. Requirement is, processing of text part should be different than the processing of files.

I have written the Choice component in for-each loop and trying to attach the files and trying to use text to log currently and in future will use it to print in email body.

Problem is with the current code Text is also getting attached as a text file in email. How to avoid text getting attached to email? also in case of multiple jpg files attachments extension is getting lost. while for single file it is working properly.

I tried to add choice component in foreach loop and tried to attach only file part of the received form-data and tried to log the text. text is getting logged in loop but after loop both the parts (file and text) are getting attached to SMTP connector.

```
  <foreach collection="#[message.inboundAttachments]" doc:name="Foreach">            


        <logger message="File name:- #[payload.dataSource.part.fileName]  Key name:- #[payload.dataSource.part.name] Content type:- #[payload.dataSource.part.contentType] contents:- #[payload.dataSource.content]." 
         level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>

        <choice doc:name="Choice">           
            <when expression="#[payload.dataSource.part.fileName == null]">
                <set-variable variableName="notificationData" value="#[payload.dataSource.content]" doc:name="Variable"/>
                <flow-ref name="testNotificationsSub_Flow" doc:name="testNotificationsSub_Flow"/>
            </when>
            <when expression="#[payload.dataSource.part.fileName != null]">
               <set-attachment attachmentName="#[payload.dataSource.part.fileName]" value="#[payload.dataSource.content]" contentType="image/jpeg" doc:name="Attachment"/>                   
            </when>
        <otherwise>
                <logger message="neither NotificationData nor file #[payload.dataSource.part.name]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>

        </otherwise>
    </choice>       

    </foreach>
```

expected output is : file should get attached and for Text part, subflow only should get excuted.Text is not attachment, so it is not supposed to get attached to email.   [postman may look like below](https://i.stack.imgur.com/txsXr.png)